# Remove/Rename Home tab Drupal 7

Tags: routes

I was wondering if it is possible to either remove or rename the "Home" tab Drupal puts in by default. The site is being used as a store/shopping cart and for it's purposes does not need a convention "Home" tab.

Comment: Hello. Could you provide screenshot? Or theme name? My Drupal does not have home tab at all, all it shows is "home" in breadcrumbs, and I did nothing to remove tabs. So, first we need to know what created tabs for you, then we might be able to tell you how to modify them.

Comment: Do you mean the Home link provided by the menu tabs in the Bartik theme? Just go to /admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu and delete it

Comment: Thanks Clive that was just what I needed as I am indeed using the Bartik theme. I am relatively new to Drupal and am still figuring out the location of all the features. Big help and thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to /admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu and it can be deleted from there.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me in drupal 6 got to

Home » Administer » Site configuration

tick this "Hide the breadcrumb if the breadcrumb only contains the link to the front page".

Answer (score 0):

FYI drupal 8:
Home » Administration » Structure » Menus 
and then select List Links, to change the name